# C# program for printing out copies

Tags: c#

My program is taking 2 dollars for each printed copy for the first 100 papers that is copied out. If the user prints out more than a hundread copies, for each copy that is above hundread it takes 1dollar per copy (So if I want to print out 101 copies, the price should be 200 + 1, 1 dollar for the 101:th copy and 2 dollars each for the first 100 copies). Here is my Code:

```
int CopyCost = 2;
        int ammountOfCopies;
        int discount = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("How many copies would you like?: ");
        ammountOfCopies = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        for (int i = 0; i < ammountOfCopies; i++)
        {
        if (ammountOfCopies > 100)
            CopyCost = 2 - discount;
        else
            CopyCost =  2;

        CopyCost *= ammountOfCopies;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The total cost for your copies is: {0} ", CopyCost);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

But the problem I have is, if I choose to write out 101 copies, it discounts every copy to 1 dollar, and not only the one above 100.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop for this problem...

Answer (score 8):

This is more a math problem than a coding one. You need to take the amount of copies at or below 100 and multiply it with the normal price. Then take the amount of copies over 100 and multiply with the discounted price. No need for the `for` loop.

Break the problem into small pieces in the code, for instance, like so:

```
int price = 2;
int discountedPrice = price - 1;
int amountAtNormalPrice = Math.Min(amountOfCopies, 100);
int amountAtDiscountPrice = Math.Max(amountOfCopies - 100, 0);
int amountTotal = (amountAtNormalPrice * price) + (amountAtDiscountedPrice * discountedPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over each of your copies (numberOfCopies, btw, not amountOfCopies) and applying the calculation each time.  You should calculate directly instead; there's no need for a loop in this situation:

```
if (numberOfCopies > 100)
{
    CopyCost = 200 + (numberOfCopies - 100);
}
else
{
    CopyCost = 2 * numberOfCopies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better, use this code:

```
int TotalCost;

if (amountOfCopies > 100)
{
    TotalCost = (amountOfCopies - 100) * (CopyCost - discount) + 100 * CopyCost;
}
else
{
    TotalCost = amountOfCopies * CopyCost;
}

Console.WriteLine("The total cost for your copies is: {0} ", TotalCost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
price = (copies * 2) - Math.Max(copies - 100, 0);
```